# Fill in missing date ranges

Tags: r, date

I have the following example data frame:

```
Date_from <- c("2013-01-01","2013-01-10","2013-01-16","2013-01-19")
Date_to <- c("2013-01-07","2013-01-12","2013-01-18","2013-01-25")
y <- data.frame(Date_from,Date_to)
y$concentration <- c("1.5","2.5","1.5","3.5")
y$Date_from <- as.Date(y$Date_from)
y$Date_to <- as.Date(y$Date_to)
y$concentration <- as.numeric(y$concentration)
```

These are measurend concentrations of heavy metals for a specific date range. However, the date ranges are not consecutive as there are gaps between 2013-01-07 to 2013-01-10 and 2013-01-12 to 2013-01-16. I need to detect those gaps, insert a row after each gap and fill it with the missing range. The result should look like this:

```
Date_from    Date_to concentration
2013-01-01 2013-01-07           1.5
2013-01-08 2013-01-09            NA
2013-01-10 2013-01-12           2.5
2013-01-13 2013-01-15            NA
2013-01-16 2013-01-18           1.5
2013-01-19 2013-01-25           3.5
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
adding <- data.frame(Date_from = y$Date_to[-nrow(y)]+1,
                     Date_to = y$Date_from[-1]-1, concentration = NA)
adding <- adding[adding$Date_from <= adding$Date_to,]
res <- rbind(y,adding)
res[order(res$Date_from),]

#   Date_from    Date_to concentration
#1 2013-01-01 2013-01-07           1.5
#5 2013-01-08 2013-01-09            NA
#2 2013-01-10 2013-01-12           2.5
#6 2013-01-13 2013-01-15            NA
#3 2013-01-16 2013-01-18           1.5
#4 2013-01-19 2013-01-25           3.5
```

Comment: I have posted this in a new question but I was wondering if I should as it here: How can I further detect the last day (Date_to) in the data frame and if this is not the last day of the year (2013-12-31) add another line with the missing last date range and add NA for concentration?

Comment: I just checked your code with another data frame and it doesn´t seem to work for cases with only 1 day missing, say `2013-01-01 to 2013-01-06` and `2013-01-08 to 2013-01-09` exist but `2013-01-07 to 2013-01-07` is missing.

Comment: See the edit. I just changed `<` with `<=` in the second line.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that requires `magrittr` and `dplyr`. It finds the gaps, then loops through to fill them.

```
# Locations to pad data frame
tmp <- which(y$Date_from-lag(y$Date_to) > 1) 
tmp <- tmp + (1:length(tmp)) - 1

for(i in tmp) {
  # Add row
  y %<>% add_row(Date_from = y$Date_to[i-1] + 1, 
                 Date_to = y$Date_from[i] - 1, 
                 .before = i)
}

#    Date_from    Date_to concentration
# 1 2013-01-01 2013-01-07           1.5
# 2 2013-01-08 2013-01-09            NA
# 3 2013-01-10 2013-01-12           2.5
# 4 2013-01-13 2013-01-15            NA
# 5 2013-01-16 2013-01-18           1.5
# 6 2013-01-19 2013-01-25           3.5
```